# Haskell: Sort an almost-sorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, haskell

I've been learning Haskell in my spare time working through [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). Would like to improve upon my Haskell (/ Functional programming) skills by solving some problems from the imperative world. One of the problems from [EPI](http://elementsofprogramminginterviews.com/) is to print an "[almost sorted array](http://elementsofprogramminginterviews.com/solutions/python/approximate_sort.py)", in a sorted fashion where it is guaranteed that no element in the array is more than `k` away from its correct position. The input is a stream of elements and the requirement is to do this in `O(n log k)` time complexity and `O(k)` space complexity.

I've attempted to re-implement the imperative solution in Haskell as follows:

```
import qualified Data.Heap as Heap

    -- print the k-sorted list in a sorted fashion
ksorted :: (Ord a, Show a) => [a] -> Int -> IO ()
ksorted [] _ = return ()
ksorted xs k = do 
    heap <- ksorted' xs Heap.empty
    mapM_ print $ (Heap.toAscList heap) -- print the remaining elements in the heap.
    where 
        ksorted' :: (Ord a, Show a) => [a] -> Heap.MinHeap a -> IO (Heap.MinHeap a)
        ksorted' [] h = return h
        ksorted' (x:xs) h = do let (m, h') = getMinAndBuildHeap h x in
                                (printMin m >> ksorted' xs h')

        printMin :: (Show a) => Maybe a -> IO ()
        printMin m = case m of 
                        Nothing     -> return ()
                        (Just item) -> print item

        getMinAndBuildHeap :: (Ord a, Show a) => Heap.MinHeap a -> a -> (Maybe a, Heap.MinHeap a)
        getMinAndBuildHeap h item= if (Heap.size h) > k 
                                   then ((Heap.viewHead h), (Heap.insert item (Heap.drop 1 h)))
                                   else (Nothing, (Heap.insert item h))
```

I would like to know a better way of solving this in Haskell. Any inputs would be appreciated.

[Edit 1]: The input is stream, but for now I assumed a list instead (with only a forward iterator/ input iterator in some sense.)

[Edit 2]: added `Data.Heap` import to the code.

Thanks.

Comment: "I would like to know a better way" - what's wrong with your way? What element of your code are you looking to improve and how?

Comment: @user2407038: This solution looks "imperative". Was hoping there is a better way which uses Haskell Features (lazy eval etc) and with a Richard Bird elegance. [Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design]

Comment: It looks imperative because you interleaving printing with logic. Write a function `ksort :: Ord a => [a] -> Int -> [a]` which sorts an 'almost' sorted array; then `ksorted xs k = print $ ksort xs k`. If the heap approach to sorting is itself too imperative for you, you should adapt your preferred sorting algorithm to an 'almost' sorted list (for e.g. insertion sort, this is very easy, since it is already based on swapping elements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main improvement is to separate the production of the sorted list from the printing of the sorted list. So:

```
import Data.Heap (MinHeap)
import qualified Data.Heap as Heap

ksort :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
ksort k xs = go (Heap.fromList b) e where
    (b, e) = splitAt (k-1) xs

    go :: Ord a => MinHeap a -> [a] -> [a]
    go heap [] = Heap.toAscList heap
    go heap (x:xs) = x' : go heap' xs where
        Just (x', heap') = Heap.view (Heap.insert x heap)

printKSorted :: (Ord a, Show a) => Int -> [a] -> IO ()
printKSorted k xs = mapM_ print (ksort k xs)
```

If I were feeling extra-special-fancy, I might try to turn `go` into a `foldr` or perhaps a `mapAccumR`, but in this case I think the explicit recursion is relatively readable, too.

Comment: I'd force the heap in the recursive case. Otherwise, consuming the list lazily and ignoring many of its elements could be bad.